# Image Hover isn't appearing in CSS but it does in HEAD

Tags: css, hover, hyperlink

```
   .cssnav  {
                        position:relative;
                        font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
                        background-image:  url(img/twitter.jpg)no-       repeat center center;
                        background-repeat: no-repeat;
                        white-space: nowrap;
                        display: block;
                        width: 211px;
                        height: 44px;
                        margin: 0;
                        padding: 0;
            }
            .cssnav a {
                        display: block;
                        color: #000000;
                        font-size: 11px;
                        width: 211px;
                        height: 44px;
                        display: block;
                        float: left;
                        color: black;
                        text-decoration: none;
            }

            .cssnav img {width: 211px; height: 44px; border: 0; }
            * html a:hover {visibility:visible}
            .cssnav a:hover img{visibility:hidden}

            .cssnav span {
                        position: absolute;
                        left: 30px;
                        top: 15px;
                        margin: 0px;
                        padding: 0px;
                        cursor: pointer;
                        width: 149px;
                        height: 14px;
                        text-align: center;
            }
            /* END OF NAVIGATION */


  }



<html>

    <head>
        <title>The history of aeronautics</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="A parallax scrolling experiment using          jQuery" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/test.css" />

    </head>

    <body>




                <!--MAIN NAVIGATION START-->

                <div class="cssnav"><a href="http://www.search-this.com/" title="Search Engine Submission"><img src="img/twitter.png" alt="Search Engine Submission" /><span>Search
                  Engine Submission</span></a></div>
                <div class="cssnav"><a href="http://www.search-this.com/website-design/" title="Website Design"><img src="img/twitter.jpg" alt="Website Design" /><span>Website
                  Design</span></a></div>




    </body>

</html>
```

I've included my CSS and HTML. I've been at this for awhile trying to figure out why it's not working... I'm using the trifecta rollover buttons code from here: http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/rollover-buttons.shtml

It works when I put the code in the  area of my HTML but not when I put it in the CSS

Comment: Your css either needs to be in a linked external stylesheet, or within <style> tags in your head element.

Comment: @AnnaThpvng Is this your whole file?

Comment: Hi there, this approach looks really dated, there are much easier ways of implementing this. Can I recommend http://kyleschaeffer.com/user-experience/pure-css-image-hover/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, first of all, as Mat said, you either need a linked style sheet by adding:

```
<link href="/fileName.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

In the head tag. Or you can add style tags like this (also within the head tag):

```
<style>
    body
    {
        background-color: #f00;
    }
</style>
```

Other than that, if you are still having trouble, I would look here:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

For the rules of specificity on CSS, however as a general rule of thumb (that I have used) on the occasion that I can't seem to pinpoint exactly why something I have specified to render doesn't render in the external css file, I will use it inline, like this:

```
<p style="background-color: #f00;">Paragraph contents...</p>
```

This is because inline CSS has a higher specificity (inherently) than an external file's CSS.